# How to lock a form in Panel Control of existing form in DevExpress?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

Am developing a small project in MS Visual Studio, I used Tool called Dev Express. In that I need to place a form in Panel Control.  I placed using this code

```
        panelControl1.Controls.Clear();
        var myForm = new newform();
        myForm.TopLevel = false;
        myForm.AutoScroll = true;
        myForm.Anchor = panelControl1.Anchor;
        panelControl1.Controls.Add(myForm);
        myForm.Show();
```

but that form is drag'able I want to fix it ? How to complete my task. Help me

Comment: You **must** set the FormBorderStyle property to None, the form's title bar cannot operate correctly when you use it as a child control.  Never use Controls.Clear().

Comment: Thank You, I got now. #Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Hans

**Form -> Properties -> FormBorderStyle -> None**